# How to get data from database and show it in selectpicker in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-5, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a form page and detail page. When I input and submit data from form page, it will redirect to detail page. And I don't know how to show the data which I submitted into a selectpicker? It showed, but double like in the image below..

```
<select id="set1" name="res_destination" class="selectpicker form-control edit" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%" disabled required>
   <option>{{ $data[0]->DESTINATION }}</option>
   <option></option>
   @foreach($destination as $getData)
      <option value="{{$getData->REF_TEXT}}"> {{$getData->REF_TEXT}} </option>
   @endforeach               
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: remove `<option>{{ $data[0]->DESTINATION }}</option>`

Comment: but if I remove that, I cannot show the option what I submit before

Comment: The idea is to show all options available and check as selected the one submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `selected` to make a dropdown value selected.

```
<select id="set1" name="res_destination" class="selectpicker form-control edit" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%" disabled required>
  @foreach($destination as $getData)
     <option value="{{$getData->REF_TEXT}}" @if($data[0]->DESTINATION==$getData->REF_TEXT) selected @endif> {{$getData->REF_TEXT}} </option>
  @endforeach
```